# Interpreting r.regression.multi

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, interpretation, regression-coefficients

This is the data output of the tool r.regression.multi on QGIS. I am new to this and cannot find good sources on how to draw conclusions for this. Therefore could someone explain; how adequately do the regressions describe meaningful relationships among the data?

X=precipitation and temperature (in the year 2050 under IPCC scenario SSP1)

y=bumblebee occurrence (current distribution)

n=43621

Rsq=0.148596

Rsqadj=0.148556

RMSE=0.126423

MAE=0.102174

F=3806.322579

b0=0.670497

AIC=-180420.870163

AICc=-180420.870163

BIC=-180394.820282

--

predictor1=rast_645a2c86c33e256

b1=-0.000001

Rsq1=0.000008

F1=0.406184

AIC1=-180422.463954

AICc1=-180422.463954

BIC1=-180415.780660

--

predictor2=rast_645a2c86c359757

b2=-0.028587

Rsq2=0.148058

F2=7585.114031

AIC2=-173429.095957

AICc2=-173429.095957

BIC2=-173422.412663

[image: map_output]
(properties table: range from red -0.0772 to blue 0.6045)

Comment: The question of "significance" in the sense of hypothesis testing ordinarily is irrelevant in this context.  There are two reasons.  First, the numbers of cells ("observations") are so large that according to any standard statistical tests the regressions will be found significant.  That means nothing.  Second, those tests usually are invalid anyway because they do not account for the *spatial correlations* expected among the residuals.  You should be asking very different questions of such regressions related to *how adequately they describe meaningful relationships among the data.*